# Is It Bad Practice to Alter Code in Order to Satisfy The Linter

Tags: python, type-hinting, static-analysis

I use neovim and use the **pyright** linter through **mason-lspconfig** in order to statically type check my code. I write many type hints; here's an example:

```
def example(user_input: str) -> None:
    tokens: List[Token] = []
    position = 0
    length_of_input: int = len(user_input)
    
    while position < length_of_input:
        match: Union[re.Match[str], None] = None

        sliced_input = user_input[position:]

        # There's more code but you probably get the point
```

I have a series of questions regarding the best practices with type hinting:

1. If a function returns None, should you still specify it like I do with the example function?
2. I see many other Python programmers use AnyStr opposed to str. I'm not asking why, I just want to know if it matters, and is it a bad practice to use str instead of AnyStr.

Here's where I get to the part about satisfying the linter. Here's what my code initially looked like:

```
# There's a lot of context that goes with this but just assume factor_node_result.tokens is a List
tokens = factor_node_result.tokens.copy()
```

The linter tells me that

```
None has no method copy()
```

I changed it to this so that it stops complaining; however, both versions of my code work. The linter just stops complaining when I use this version:

```
if factor_node_result.tokens is not None:
    tokens = factor_node_result.tokens.copy()
```

1. Is there anyway I can use type hinting magic or configure my linter to somehow ignore this kind of check
2. Is it a bad practice to change code in order to satisfy the linter?

Comment: You should provide source or a reference for `factor_node_result.tokens` - it's unclear if `tokens` could actually return `None` or whether the linter is wrong and you have some other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thing is, if you have a good linter and you write decent code, whatever the linter complains about is a potential issue with your code.

"But it works without the type" does not change that. For one, Python always works without the type hints, that's not why it's there. Secondly, unless you know absolutely sure that it will work for any possible value, you can't really say it works. And even then, the fact that it works now, doesn't mean it will still work in the future, when you call a function from somewhere else, or perhaps run the script on a new version of Python, with different dependencies, etc.

As for checking for `None`, yes you should in some cases, if the function can reasonably return `None` (or exit without explicitly returning anything, which is the same). For example:

```
from typing import Optional


def question(answer: bool) -> Optional[int]:
    if answer:
        return 42


wisdom = question(False)

if wisdom is None:
    print("You're not worthy!")
else:
    print(f"Your answer is {wisdom}")
```

However, a function that always returns `None` (i.e. that solely relies on side effects, or is just a method operating on an object) shouldn't need the hint. After all, you wouldn't be calling methods on `None`.

All four questions:

- ***If a function returns `None`, should you still specify it like I do with the example function?***
  Only if that makes it more clear to read, or if your tools can't figure out the return type without it. (and obviously not unless it's true)
- ***[does using AnyStr matter], and is it a bad practice to use `str` instead of `AnyStr`.***
  Yes it matters, since `AnyStr` includes both `bytes` and `str`. No, it's not bad practice to use `str`, if your code doesn't support `bytes`, you should use `str`. (keep in mind that it has to be either `str` or `bytes` for all instances of use in a single signature)
- ***Is there any way I can use type hinting magic or configure my linter to somehow ignore this kind of check?***
  Most linters and the like allow you to turn off certain checks, but you typically want to scope that type of change as narrowly as possible (some hinters and linters allow you to use annotations to only turn off the check for a single command, block, or other element). It can be a good idea when the linter is right but you can't help the problem (like a minor bug in a library you're using for example, or a problem with the linter itself). But in most cases, the warning will be there for a reason.
- ***Is it a bad practice to change code in order to satisfy the linter?***
  Not if you're using good tools. The linter will be warning because your code could cause trouble, even if it doesn't in practice right now. Changing the code in a way that satisfies the linter should typically help prevent problems down the line.

Finally, here's an example where a linter will typically fail, and where specifying `-> None` helps:

```
def fn(x):
    def always_true():
        return True
    if always_true():
        return
    return x


def stripped_lower(x: str):
    return x.lower().strip()


stripped_lower(fn('test'))
```

This code will look fine to many linter and analysis tools. However, to you and me it should be clear that the function `fn()` can only ever return `None`, due to what `always_true()` returns. However, to a linter, `True` is just a runtime `bool` value, and it won't use that in its analysis, since a `bool` might be `False` as well. So, from its point of view, `fn('test')` may well return a string. `stripped_lower()` is clear about expecting a string, but will fail with an exception if passed `None` - which it always will.

If you change the signature to `def fn(x) -> None:`, your tools will pick up on the problem and correctly show a type warning.

Note that I said "a function that always returns `None` shouldn't need the hint" - that's true here as well. Although providing the hint helps here, this function is poorly written and rewriting it so that it doesn't need the hint would be better than adding the type hint. However, sometimes you don't have that luxury (perhaps you don't control the problematic parts of the code) and then adding the hint may be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

**Python Type Hinting**

1. Explicitly declaring that your function's return type is `None` is not necessary, but makes it clearer to readers looking at your function.
2. Per the [Python typing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.AnyStr), `AnyStr` is specifically used when you want your function to either take `bytes` or a `str`, and you don't want them to mix (a function that takes an `AnyStr` and returns an `AnyStr` must either take `bytes` and return `bytes` or take `str` and return `str`, it can't take `str` and return `bytes`). If this doesn't fit your use case, just use `str`.

**Linting**

1. Many linters, [including Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/2477) do have an option to disable specific rules, but for something like this, adjusting your type hints is a better way to resolve the issue. Setting the type to assert that it isn't `None` (as long as you're sure that it never will be) will resolve the linter error.
2. No, it's not bad practice to change code in order to satisfy a linter, but you should understand why the linter is complaining. In this example, the type hints are telling it that there is a possibility that `factor_node_results.tokens` is `None`, which either means that the types are inaccurate or that it is indeed possible for that value to be `None`, in which case adding a check is entirely appropriate.